# Servicemix freezing while installing bundled features

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

The command:

```
feature:install spring-jdbc/4.3.5.RELEASE_1
```

causes my Servicemix 7.0.1 instance to freeze indefinetely, whereas
the same command (with lower feature version) works like a charm in Servicemix 5. Am I doing something wrong? Or is Servicemix 7 buggy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I *believe* that the Karaf version on which this release of Servicemix is based on
was bugged:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-4272

New version, which I compiled and tested personally, doesn't freeze.

There is still no new Servicemix in sight, so I suggest using Karaf and its features - it's not as barebone as one would think. Moreover, Karaf has live and kicking user mailing list:
http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf-User-f930749.html